# Advice on developing an application on iOS with a chat side

Tags: ios, swift, chat

Looking at the title you can pretty much understand what I want to say and I don't think there is anything else to add.

This far I created a simple twisted  server that handles the most basic things[logging in and broadcasting a message to everybody on the server ] , as I am thinking further and further about the end product, I am beginning to wonder if this is the best choice

I know there are protocols like XMPP that I can use but I thought creating a server from scratch especially for this app would  be better.

Is my idea wrong or should I keep on going with it?Or any other advices you can give me fell free to shoot

Not that it makes any difference but I am writing this app entirely in swift.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced your title provided the full intent you were after. If you are after a chat client for iOS in swift you might try looking at [LightStreamer](http://www.lightstreamer.com) which is a server model for streaming content using an array of mechanisms.

An iOS library is available which you can use within your swift based application.